# How to change the border style when click expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, border

I am creating a button where I want to click and expand, and get rid of the bottom border and when I expand it I want the bottom border to come back, so I create a function where when I click once, its modulo cannot divide by two and when I click one more time, which is collapse, the count for the button to click is 2 so it can be divided by 2. Below is my code but I don't know why it won't work.

```
<script>
 function hideBorder() {
      var count = 0;
      var btn = document.getElementById("chi");
      if (btn.onclick) {
        count++;
      }

      if (count % 2 == 0) {
        doucment.getElementById("chi").style.borderBottom = "2px solid #65daff";
        document.getElementById("chi").style.borderEndEndRadius = "10px";
        document.getElementById("chi").style.borderEndStartRadius = "10px";
      } else if (count % 2 == 1) {
        doucment.getElementById("chi").style.borderBottom = "none";
        document.getElementById("chi").style.borderEndEndRadius = "0px";
        document.getElementById("chi").style.borderEndStartRadius = "0px";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have to make count a global variable. Currently, every time you call that function, it will have its value set to 0. Also, you can use a boolean flag for this purpose, look it up!

Comment: You have a typo in the `doucment` -- should be `document`, also you don't need to `document.getElementById` every time -- you already have `var btn`. And you don't need the `counter` -- check whether the border is set instead.

Comment: @Kosh Thank you very much, I had solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

having the `count` variable inside the function means everytime the function is being called, `count`'s value resets to 0. fixing it is as simple as moving the declaration of `count` outside of the function, making it "global".

Comment: Alright, I had solve the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;
function hideBorder() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("chi");
  if (btn.onclick) {
    count++;
  }
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    btn.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #65daff";
    btn.style.borderEndEndRadius = "10px";
    btn.style.borderEndStartRadius = "10px";
  } else if (count % 2 == 1) {
    btn.style.borderBottom = "none";
    btn.style.borderEndEndRadius = "0px";
    btn.style.borderEndStartRadius = "0px";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="chi" onclick="hideBorder()">click</button>
```

Comment: increment code may not work.